# Can an app access screen of another app in android?

Tags: android, permissions, screen-recording

I would like my app to scan text that another app renders on the screen, for example scan subtitles.
Is that possible in Android?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can capture the screen using the MediaProjection APIs.  Request permission via [MediaProjectionManager.createScreenCaptureIntent()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/projection/MediaProjectionManager.html#createScreenCaptureIntent()) and then [use the resulting `MediaProjection` object](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/projection/MediaProjection.html#createVirtualDisplay(java.lang.String,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20android.view.Surface,%20android.hardware.display.VirtualDisplay.Callback,%20android.os.Handler)) to render the screen to a Surface.

Note that for subtitles specifically, you may be unable to see them if the app displaying them is showing DRM-protected content.